# How to search for 'following' elements till we reach an element in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For example,

We have the following HTML :

```
<li class="gcui-menu-item tsc-dr-tree-item">1</li>
<li class="gcui-menu-item tsc-dr-tree-subitem">1-1</li>
<li class="gcui-menu-item tsc-dr-tree-subitem">1-2</li>
<li class="gcui-menu-item tsc-dr-tree-item">2</li>
<li class="gcui-menu-item tsc-dr-tree-subitem">2-1</li>
```

NOTE: The text contained in the `li`s are not actually present on the page, they are there as labels to help explain the problem.

Here, I would like to get the subitems, '1-1' and '1-2', only below the first tree item, '1'.

If I search for:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'tree-item')]//following::li[contains(@class, 'subitem')]
```

I also get the subitem below the second tree item, '2-1', since this structure does not have subitems as children of the item but siblings.

So is there any way where we can do `following:: li` until we reach an `li` element? Maybe `following::li` until the next `li` containing 'tree-item' in its class?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you try, and please put here html, instead of photo.

Comment: I reworded your question based on what I think you are asking. Please edit it and correct anything that I got wrong.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks so much for editing my question, it is perfect. Now I have an idea about how I can explain better, I will improve my questions from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath that matches both the li subitem elements under first menu-item.

```
//li[contains(@class,'tree-item')][1]/following-sibling::li[contains(@class,'tree-subitem') and count(preceding-sibling::li[contains(@class,'tree-item')])=1]
```

Below is the output in chrome console.
[image]

Comment: If you want to get the subitems for the 2nd menu-item, then just replace the position `1` to `2` in both the places. FYI

Comment: This is returning no items

Comment: I figured out what the issue is... `menu-subitem` should be `tree-subitem`... but it still doesn't return the right items. It only returns the first item, not all (2) subitems.

Comment: you might night updated the last class ref to 'tree-item'. I updated the xpath, based on the updated post, it should sync with the class name now as per the post.

Comment: Cool. Please accept my answer. I think the post was updated after my original response, that's why I have to edit the post with new class names :-).

Comment: It's not my question. I was just looking for an answer and thought you were on the right path but it didn't quite work.